# React Navigation mounts a screen then doesn't accept the new params passed again from another screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am passing some params from screen A to screen B using the following code

```
props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "xyz"
});
```

The params are received on ScreenB and when I go back to Screen A and update the state and new params are passed to the navigate function, the new params are not received on Screen B instead it retains the old params passed to it.

I know that it has been mounted first hence react navigation doesn't re mount it and there are lifecycle events for [React Navigation Lifecycle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle/#react-navigation-lifecycle-events) but I can't understand as to where the `useFocusEffect` hook is to be used so that the new params are passed and the Screen B is re-rendered

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the route params for `ScreenB` won't specifically trigger a re-render. Like you said, you need a `useFocusEffect` hook to update `ScreenB` whenever refocus occurs. Then you can read the route params.

Try adding to `ScreenB`:

```
import { useIsFocused } from 'react-navigation/native'

...

// inside component

const isFocused = useIsFocused()

useEffect(() => {
  if (isFocused) {
    // do something with params
  }
}, [isFocused])
```

Comment: On Screen B I am using useState to set the values from the route params to a state const. Also I have tried `useFocusEffect` and inside I had console.log the route params and they were the same and not the new ones that I was passing

Comment: That's really strange. What happens if you use `props.navigation.push()` instead of `props.navigation.navigate`? Also are you sure you're using `useIsFocused`? Because it's different than `useFocusEffect` in that it triggers a re-render on focus.

Comment: I haven't tried `useIsFocused` yet. I will try it and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @ShahzebQureshi did you resolve this one? I'm facing it now